# Глобальный слушатель

Tags: java, клавиатура, мышь

Можно ли в java сделать так что-бы при нажатии клавиши или ЛКП вне компонента, можно было вызвать метод.

типа нажал в google chrome VK_F и в этот момент сработал слушатель java.

похоже мне нужен KeyLogger.

Comment: вторая ссылка гугла https://github.com/vakho10/Java-Keylogger

Comment: Как добавить библиотеку  org.jnativehook

Comment: Я смог его подключить но он выдает такую ошибку:
апр. 22, 2020 9:28:09 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen getAutoRepeatRate
INFO: hook_get_auto_repeat_rate [135]: SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED: 31.

апр. 22, 2020 9:28:09 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen getAutoRepeatDelay
INFO: hook_get_auto_repeat_delay [149]: SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY: 1.

апр. 22, 2020 9:28:09 PM org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen getMultiClickIterval
INFO: hook_get_multi_click_time [208]: GetDoubleClickTime: 500.

Comment: Я уже этим не занимаюсь, но хотелось уточнить то что он должен был работать всегда, типа в игре или в виртуальной машине.